# React toggle "Show All" and "Show Winners" doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have been struggling on this piece of codes which I suppose a button's clicked, the table will toggle between **show all items** and **show winner items** only.

Problem: The button has to be clicked two times to show winner items. Can't revert back to show all.

Do appreciate if someone can help. Thank you so much.

```
const MovieList = () => {    
    // Get Movies
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [winner, filterWinner] = useState(false)

    const fetchMovies = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/data')
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
        
    }

    useEffect(() => { 
    const getMovies = async () => {
      const moviesFromServer = await fetchMovies()
        setMovies(moviesFromServer)

    }
    getMovies()
    }, [])

   
    //toggle between setting movies to all movies and winner movies.
    //movie is an object that has a key and value pair "winner" : "True" or "winner" : "False"
    const toggleWinner = () => {
      filterWinner(!winner)
      if (winner === true) {
        const winners = movies.filter((movie) => movie.winner === 'True');
        setMovies(winners);
      } else {
        setMovies(movies);
      }
  }
    
    return (
      
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Movies</h1>
        <hr />
        <div>
          <Button onClick={toggleWinner} color="info">{winner ? "Show All" : "Show Winners"}</Button>
        </div>
            
      <div>
        <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Film Name</th>
              <th>Oscar Winner</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                {movies.map(movie => (
                <tr key={movie.id}>
                <td>{movie.year}</td>
                <td>{movie.filmName}</td>
                <td>{movie.winner}</td>
                <td>{movie.country}</td>
            </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
          </table>
          
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default MovieList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is when you set state, that state will not be updated immediately, so you can't compare `winner` to `true`.

You can try this approach

```
const toggleWinner = () => {
    //winner = false
    filterWinner(prev => {
        if(!prev) { // winner = true
            const winners = movies.filter((movie) => movie.winner === "True");
            setMovies(winners);
        }
        else {
            setMovies(movies);
        }
        return !prev
    });
};
```

Another problem is that you mutated the `movies`, so when you toggle again, old `movies` value is gone.

Check this codesandbox to see how I fixed that: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-browser-o8jeb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you. I've implementeded your codes. When the button's first clicked, show winners work. But when it's clicked again, it doens't revert back to show all. Please advise.

Comment: @SimonS. please try again, I've edited the code

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: @SimonS. I added the demo link, check that out

Comment: Millions of thanks, Dave.

Comment: @SimonS. please vote or mark my answer as helpful if that helped you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237909/discussion-between-simon-s-and-dave-runner).

Answer (score 0):

If your state change depends on previous state value you need to call a function inside your update function.

const [state,setState]=useState(false);

If you want to toggle the state value you need to call update function like this.

setState(state=>!state)

In your case

filterWinner(winner=>!winner)

Note: you can use any name you want as argument inside update function.