# Need explanations for 'React toggle "Show All" and "Show Winners" doesn't work'

Tags: reactjs

I have hard time understand this block of code in this post.

**To be specific: I observed that the button is first clicked, the movies array is filtered to show the winners only, which means this part of the if/else statement has been executed. But why 'prev' is changed to '!prev', before the return !prev at the end of the filterWinner function?**

```
if (!prev) {
        // winner = true
        console.log(prev);
        const winners = movies.filter((movie) => movie.winner === "True");
        setFilteredMovies(winners);
      }
```

Could someone please explain this piece of code to me? Thank you.

The Post:
[React toggle "Show All" and "Show Winners" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458642/react-toggle-show-all-and-show-winners-doesnt-work/69458902#69458902)

[The full solution code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-browser-o8jeb?file=/src/App.js)

```
const toggleWinner = () => {
    //winner = false
    filterWinner(prev => {
        if(!prev) { // winner = true
            const winners = movies.filter((movie) => movie.winner === "True");
            setMovies(winners);
        }
        else {
            setMovies(movies);
        }
        return !prev
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterWinner` should perhaps be named `setWinner` or `setWinnerFilter`.

If a function is passed when setting a React state like that, whatever is returned at the end of the function is the new `winner` state. Since we return `!prev`, we invert whatever boolean value that `winner`. Hence, it toggles `winner` between `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The `if (!prev)` checks to see if `prev` is falsey. It basically says "if prev doesn't exist or if prev is false".

The `return !prev` part will return the opposite of the current `prev` value. So if `prev` is `true` and you call `return !prev` it will return false since it is the "opposite" of true.

This demo should clear it up:

```js
console.log(`!true should be false. '${!true}'`);
console.log(`!false should be true. '${!false}'`);
```